# Weird Behavior Using MOQ

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am experiencing some weird behavior using MOQ in my unit tests:

Given the following test:

```
[Fact]
public void ShoppingCart_ShouldIncrementQuantity_WhenAddingDuplicateItem()
{
    var cart = new ShoppingCart();

    var item1 = GetMockItem("Test");
    var item2 = GetMockItem("Test", quantity: 2);

    cart.AddItem(item1.Object);
    cart.AddItem(item2.Object);

    cart.Items.Single(x => x.Sku == "Test").Quantity
        .Should().Be(3);
}

private Mock<IShoppingCartItem> GetMockItem(string sku, decimal price = 10, int quantity = 1)
{
    var mock = new Mock<IShoppingCartItem>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Sku).Returns(sku);
    mock.Setup(x => x.Price).Returns(price);
    mock.Setup(x => x.Quantity).Returns(quantity);

    return mock;
}
```

And this is the code under test:

```
public void AddItem(IShoppingCartItem item)
{
    Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");

    var existingItem = this.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Sku == item.Sku);

    if (existingItem != null)
    {
        existingItem.Quantity += item.Quantity;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I am getting this result: `Test 'Titan.Tests.ShoppingCartTests.ShoppingCart_ShouldIncrementQuantity_WhenAddingDuplicateItem' failed: Expected 3, but found 1.`

I am baffled or I am just having a dumb moment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you haven't told Moq what to do when the Quantity property is set.
By default, Moq doesn't just assume that all of your properties should be simple getter/setters. It's up to you to decide what to do with them.

You have a couple of options.

**Use SetupAllProperties() to tell Moq to treat properties as simple getter/setters.**

```
  private Mock<IShoppingCartItem> GetMockItem(string sku, decimal price = 10, int quantity = 1)
  {
        var mock = new Mock<IShoppingCartItem>();
        mock.SetupAllProperties();

        // Set the properties like normal properties. Moq will do the right thing.
        mock.Object.Sku = sku;
        mock.Object.Price = price;
        mock.Object.Quantity = quantity;
        return mock;
  }
```

**Use SetupSet to handle the case where the Quantity property is set, and in its callback, re-setup the property getter, so that it returns the new value.**

```
  private Mock<IShoppingCartItem> GetMockItem(string sku, decimal price = 10, int quantity = 1)
  {
        var mock = new Mock<IShoppingCartItem>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.Sku).Returns(sku);
        mock.Setup(x => x.Price).Returns(price);
        mock.Setup(x => x.Quantity).Returns(quantity);

        // You can call Setups from within Setups
        mock.SetupSet(x => x.Quantity).Callback(q => mock.Setup(x => x.Quantity).Returns(q));
        return mock;
  }
```

Alternately, you could also change your design so that you aren't modifying public properties.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this `Alternately, you could also change your design so that you aren't modifying public properties.`?

Comment: Well, as a quick example, you could have an UpdateQuantity(int newQuantity) method on IShoppingCartItem which you call inside of AddItem(). Then, instead of checking if Quantity is 3 at the end of your test, you would check to make sure UpdateQuantity was called:  item1.Verify(i => i.UpdateQuantity(3))

Answer (score 1):

The mocked property of the first item is set up to always return 1. It doesn't matter you add 2 to it then, it will always return 1.

Edit: your += is ignored because your cart stores mocked objects. The one that gets to the cart first is mocked to ALWAYs returns 1.

Comment: But they are different instances of the Mock. I don't get it, shouldn't those be completely separate of each other?

Comment: They are but you set up BOTH. The first always returns 1, the second always returns 2. Then, you find first and how do you expect it to return 3 if you set it up to return 1? The "+" is just ignored!

Comment: I dont ever find first. I call `Single` and when I debug the code it all works except the fact that it does not increment the quantity.

Comment: In the AddItem method, if the item is not found you add it to the cart. The first time you add the item, the mocked item is stored, the one that ALWAYS returns 1. It will ALWAYS return 1. Your += works on MOCKED object, not a real one!

Comment: OK, So these mocked objects do not behave like a regular object? Wow!! I am totally off in my understanding of the benefit of a mocking framework then. So in this case, what is the benefit of even using MOQ? If I can't modify the state of a mocked object, then they seem pretty rigid to me.

Comment: You can modify the state but not that by setting the mock to always return the same value. Attach a custom callback instead.